# 2d Circle different ARC's Collision detection

Tags: collision-detection

I've read about the way to detect collision between 2 circles or circle and line
using [trigonometry](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769).

But now I would like be able to detect which part of the circle arcs I'm hitting.
For example I divided my circle to 4 different sized arcs.
I would like to know which arc gets hit, 1, 2, 3, or 4?
See image:
[image]
What is the best collision detection algorithm for this? Or what is this called?

Comment: The algorithm you linked already do that: the *a* and *b* forms direction vector which tells what arc(wedge) was hit "the most". To evaluate it, it is important how are your arcs defined? Cw/ccw angles from reference vector(e.g. up) or as vectors in local space?

Comment: sorry but i didnt saw it in the tutorial , i only saw how to hit 1 point in the circle